# Cant find included class in controller. Zend Framework 2

Tags: class, zend-framework2, structure

Also i begin learning zend framework 2. Install skillet application with composel. All goes fine until i didnt begin read that chapter http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html
in part where i try to create new class object in controller /src/Album/controller/AlbumController.php in function addAction().

There my PHP error:
http://i63.fastpic.ru/big/2014/1201/93/9684e5bcc24b52fec546f07e90abe593.png

There my IDE:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Album\Model\Album;
use Album\Form\AlbumForm; //COLORED RED "Form"

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $albumTable;

public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
}

public function addAction()
{
    $form = new AlbumForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $album = new Album(); //THE EEROR STRING THAT I GET IN PHP.
        $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $album->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($album);

            // Redirect to list of albums
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

Comment: The error indicates ZF can't find the AlbumForm class - where is that class located?

Comment: That class located in Album/src/Album/Form/AlbumForm.php

Comment: There folder structure http://i65.fastpic.ru/big/2014/1201/92/d5cea034fc38e357a058d3434688ee92.png

Comment: That looks ok - what does your autoloader configuration in Module.php look like, and the AlbumForm class itself?